# Are average daily temperatures affected by DST?

Tags: temperature, measurements

To calculate the average daily temperatures, do meteo professionals still use the Mannheim procedure with twice weighted measurement in the evening?
 (It could be obsolete by automated weather stations.)

If so, does DST affect the daily average by getting that measurement one hour earlier?

I'm not asking if that invalidates the results, just whether there is a measurable impact.

Comment: AFAIK, they use BOTH local time and UTC as in [Shouthern Asia Climate Assessment & Data Set Data Dictionary](http://saca-bmkg.knmi.nl/dailydata/datadictionaryelement.php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They compensate for DST.

That is, for any daily measurement, they use the same universal time every day of the year.  If they take a measurement at 7:00 local time in summer, they will take the same measurement at 6:00 in winter.

(So if you do see a DST effect in the data, that would be due to traffic and other local anthropogenic effects shifting by an hour relative to the time of measurement!  Perhaps due to urban heat island effect, or forcing by anthropogenic aerosols from traffic or industry.)

Comment: When I first saw the question title, I thought it was going to be about the anthro effects - now _that_ would be interesting to discover! Of course scientists make timed measurements in a consistent timebase (i.e. usually UTC); timezone offsets (inc. daylight savings) are just a display layer!

Comment: About the antrho effects of DST - I hereby invoke Newton's flaming laser sword.

Comment: This question appears to be asking about anthro effects: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/do-humans-cause-a-dst-related-shift-in-average-daily-temperatures